# How do I get textviews on button click from a recycleview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-button

I have a `recycleView` containing n reviews. Each review has a nickname, body and a `button` that gives the opportunity to report my review if something is wrong. Problem is I don't know how to retrieve these info on click. Can someone show me some code draft maybe?

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do that is making a interface, here i put an example.

```
class NewsAdapter(private val noticias: List<Noticia>, private val layout: Int, private val activity: Activity, private val listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(noticias[position], listener)
}

override fun getItemCount() = noticias.size

// ViewHolder
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    
    fun bind(noticia: Noticia, listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        itemView.textViewNewsTitulo.text = noticia.titulo
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(noticia.foto_url)
                .fitCenter()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(itemView.imageViewNews)
        itemView.textViewNewsDesc.text = noticia.desc

        // bind the click listener with the itemView
        itemView.setOnClickListener { listener.onItemClick(noticia, adapterPosition) }
    }
}

// Interface onClick define in adapter adapter
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(noticia: Noticia?, posicion: Int)
} 
}
```

For use in your activity you need to implement the interface like this.

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), NewsAdapter.OnItemClickListener
```

The interface force you to implement the methods in the activity.

```
override fun onItemClick(noticia: Noticia?, posicion: Int) {
        // do your logic on click 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your RecyclerView class override the following:

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

//assuming your 'body' is TextView:
TextView tv = holder.body; //body should have been set in your ViewHolder inner class
Button button = holder.button; //assume button was defined in your ViewHolder inner class

//now you have a reference to your objects!

}
```